# Why homepage loaded before app.component.ts

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want the homepage to be loaded when everything is ready, but it loads before app.component.ts, which I think it caused provider can't work properly because of all the import things not fully processed.

I did everything that I know to make the homepage lazy load, but console.log still show the homepage loaded before app.component.ts.

Here is my `app.module.ts`, which I import homepage module instead of homepage:

```
import { HomePageModule } from '../pages/home/home.module';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    TabsPageModule,
    HomePageModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is my `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { firebaseConfig } from './credential'
import firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = 'TabsPage';

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });

    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      console.log('Processing app.component.ts')
      if (!user) {
        this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
        unsubscribe();
      } else {
        this.rootPage = 'TabsPage';
        unsubscribe();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my `tabs.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = 'HomePage';
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ContactPage;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Below is my `home.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, ) {
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('homePage loaded')
  }
}
```

Below is what it show in my `console.log`:

```
'homePage loaded'
'Processing app.component.ts'
```

Please advise how to make the `homepage` load after `app.component.ts`, because if it loads before `app.component.ts`, then it will cause the firebase code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the initialization you did during the variable declaration of `rootPage` in app.component.ts.

```
rootPage:any = 'TabsPage';
```

Change it to:

```
rootPage:any;
```

As it will initially set the TabsPage which has the first tab as HomePage.